# looping through an array in an array php

Tags: php

I have an output of the following flight information.

```
    array(1) {
      ["ArrivedResult"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["next_offset"]=>
        int(10)
        ["arrivals"]=>
        array(10) {
          [0]=>
          array(10) {
            ["ident"]=>
            string(4) "SWA9"
            ["aircrafttype"]=>
            string(4) "B737"
            ["actualdeparturetime"]=>
            int(1532097153)
            ["actualarrivaltime"]=>
            int(1532100120)
            ["origin"]=>
            string(4) "KDAL"
            ["destination"]=>
            string(4) "KHOU"
            ["originName"]=>
            string(17) "Dallas Love Field"
            ["originCity"]=>
            string(10) "Dallas, TX"
            ["destinationName"]=>
            string(15) "William P Hobby"
            ["destinationCity"]=>
            string(11) "Houston, TX"
          }
```

I am trying to access the data **destination** I have tried to used the following code

```
        foreach ($coded_json['DepartedResult']['departures'] as $key => $value) {
            echo $value;
        }
```

I get the following error

> Notice:  Array to string conversion in

Comment: I don't see anything about `DepartedResult` or `departures` in that array

Comment: What @PatrickQ said, but probably `$coded_json['DepartedResult']['departures'][0]`

Comment: You might want to look at [is_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php). Really though just use `var_dump` and play with it till you understand the array structure.

Comment: Check it using var_dump($value)

Comment: I'm not sure ,but reading your previous posts and how varied they are (Not on one particular area but covering many types).  May I ask if you are a Full Stack Developer or a Student?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `departures` is like `arrivals` in your question, it's a 2-dimensional array of associative arrays. You need to access the `destination` property.

```
foreach ($coded_json['DepartedResult']['departures'] as $key => $value) {
    echo $value['destination'] . '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code what I have understood is that you want iterate array, so here is working code which I have tested

```
$coded_json = array(
                    "DepartedResult" => array("next_offset"=>10,
                    "departures"=>array(array("ident"=>"SWA9",
                                        "aircrafttype"=>"B737",
                                        "actualdeparturetime"=>1532097153,
                                        "actualarrivaltime"=>1532100120,
                                        "origin"=>"KDAL",
                                        "destination"=>"KHOU",
                                        "originName"=>"Dallas Love Field",
                                        "originCity"=>"Dallas, TX",
                                        "destinationName"=>"William P Hobby",
                                        "destinationCity"=>"Houston, TX",
                                  ))));

foreach ($coded_json['DepartedResult'][0]['departures'] as $key => $value) {
    echo '<br/>'.$value;
}
```

**Output**

```
SWA9
B737
1532097153
1532100120
KDAL
KHOU
Dallas Love Field
Dallas, TX
William P Hobby
Houston, TX
```

You can access **destination** as following:

```
echo $coded_json['DepartedResult']['departures'][0]['destination'];
```

Comment: Your `departures` is a single associative array. In the question it's a 2-dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($coded_json["ArrivedResult"]["arrivals"] as $foo){
    var_dump($foo['destination']);
}
```